# How to use OAuth 2.0 GitHub token in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

- `GIVEN`:

`Spring Boot App`, `GitHub Client ID`, `GitHub Client Secret`

`SecurityConfiguration` class:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  private final AuthenticationExceptionHandler authenticationExceptionHandler;
  private final AccessDeniedExceptionHandler accessDeniedExceptionHandler;
  private final OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> oAuth2UserService;

@Bean
  protected SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests(a -> a
            .antMatchers("/", "/login/**", "/error", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .exceptionHandling(e -> e
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationExceptionHandler)
            .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedExceptionHandler)
        )
        .csrf(c -> c
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        )
        .logout(l -> l
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
        )
        .oauth2Login();

    return http.build();
  }
```

- `WHEN`:

Send a request `GET http://{server:port}/oauth2/authorization/github` using `Postman`, I get in response:

```
Token Name:GitHub Token
Access Token: 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
Token Type: bearer
scope: read%3Auser
access_token_url: https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token
client_id: 8946552286f96669e25a
client_secret: efd47baa823358fbbf109c5249e2699612ab44b2
timestamp: 1680770881579
```

- `What I do`:

I add the following content to the `GET http://{server:port}/api/v1/users` request `GitGub Access Token` header:

```
Authorization: Bearer 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
```

- `THEN`:

I got error:

```
{
    "httpStatus": "UNAUTHORIZED",
    "exceptionBody": {
        "errorMessages": [
            "Access denied. Only authenticated users can perform this action"
        ],
        "errorCode": 40106
    }
}
```

- `QUESTIONS`:

How can I continue to use this received toke when sending subsequent requests?

Inside `Spring Boot` is there somewhere to check the validity of this token?

I'm waiting inside the Spring Boot application (perhaps in the filter chain) to validate the GitHub token.

Answer (score 3):

You are obviously lacking some [background about OAuth2](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#1-oauth2-essentials) and should clarify your intention. Are you trying to:

- call Github APIs from your Spring application (which makes it a client)
- authorize requests to a REST API using a Bearer access token (like you seem to be doing in your question and makes your app a resource server)

You wrote OAuth2 client configuration (login and logout) => requests intercepted by this security filter-chain are secured with sessions, not access tokens. **`STATELESS` session creation policy is incoherent with the rest of your conf** (understand: this won't work).

A REST API secured with access tokens is a resource server and a resource server does not care about login and logout which are client business (and require state, usually a session, to store tokens).

To make your app a resource server, check your dependencies (use `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`, not `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`), and apply [resource server configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/opaque-token.html) (remove login, logout, authentication entry point, user info and user service)

Warning: your token is not a JWT string. You'll have to introspect it (configure your resource server for "opaque" tokens), which is quite inefficient and hardly acceptable with a remote authorization server. You'd better use an authorization server of your own with "social login" features and issuing JWTs (Keycloak, Auth0, Cognito and almost any other OIDC Provider have this kind of "Login with..." feature)

I have written quite a few [tutorials around OAuth2](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials). You'll find complete configuration samples there. **Do not skip the OAuth2 essentials section** I already linked in the first sentence. It covers differences between OAuth2 clients and OAuth2 resource server as well as between introspection and JWT decoding.